# Counting certain graphs defined over consecutive sets of natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, graph-theory, trees

Let $[n] = \{1,\ldots, n\}$ and call a subset $M \subseteq [n]$ a consecutive subset if $$M = \{m,m+1,\ldots,m+|M|-1\}$$
for some $m \in [n]$, i.e., $M$ contains a smallest and a largest number and all numbers in between, or equivalently if $x,y \in M$ implies $z \in M$ for all $x \le z \le y$.

Consider directed graphs $G_n = (V, E)$ with vertex set $V \subseteq \{ M \subseteq [n] \mid M \mbox{ is consecutive } \}$ and edge set $E = \{ (N, M) \in V\times V\mid M \subseteq N \land |N\setminus M| = 1 \}$ with the additonal constraint that from $[n]$ we have at least one path to every other vertex and $[n] \in V$.

For example if $n = 3$ one such graph is:

[image: example]

and in total we have $17$ different such graphs for $n = 3$, one of these is the above and the other are:

[image: all-graphs]

Note that by the additional requirement that we have a path from $\{1,2,3\}$ to every other vertex, for example the graph $G = (V, E)$ with $V = \{\{1,2,3\}, \{1\}\}$ and $E = \emptyset$ is excluded.

How to count the number of such graphs for given $n$? For $n = 1$ we have one,
for $n = 2$ we have $4$ and for $n = 3$ we have $17$. I cannot count inductively because certain nodes (like $\{2\}$ in the above example) get merged, so I cannot give an inductive formula by counting sub-graphs and constructing a new graph.

Comment: If you count the number for $4$ by hand you may find the sequence in OEIS.  $2,5,12$ gives $529$ results, which is a lot to go through

Comment: I'm a little confused with some omissions: why no $\{1,2,3\} \rightarrow \{1,2\} \rightarrow \{2\}$? Why not the 2 vertex graph with $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1\}$ with no edges? Why no $\{1,2\} \rightarrow \{1\}$? These don't seem to be omitted by your definition of the graphs you want to look at.

Comment: @user113102 Thanks for noticing. The graph $\{1,2,3\} \rightarrow \{1,2\} \rightarrow \{2\}$ was overlooked, I simply forgot it! I also wanted the resulting graphs to be connected, that why $V = \{ \{1,2,3\}, \{1\} \}$ is excluded. I will update my question!

Comment: You are also missing $\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow \{2,3\} \rightarrow \{2\}$. I'm also counting 11 in your image above. So you also require that $[n]$ is a vertex?

Comment: For $n=2$ it seems like it should be $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,2\}\rightarrow \{1\}$, $\{1,2\}\rightarrow \{2\}$, and $\{1\} \leftarrow \{1,2\}\rightarrow \{2\}$. What am I missing?

Comment: @user113102 $G = ([n], \emptyset)$ is counted too, so $[n]$ is also a vertex, but also $G = (\emptyset, \emptyset)$. This last one is the one you are missing for $n = 2$.

Comment: So does it have to include $[n]$ as a vertex? If so, why do I count $G = (\emptyset , \emptyset )$? If not, why don't I count $\{2,3\} \rightarrow \{3\}$ for $n=3$ as a valid graph? Just trying to understand the problem statement.

Comment: @user113102 Yes, my fault. Thanks you, yes $[n]$ has to be included, then surely $G = (\emptyset, \emptyset)$ is not a valid example. I will update my question immediately!

Comment: Consider the case when $V$ includes $\{1,2,3\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}$.   Since each of the $3$ singleton leaves can be included or excluded independently, there must be $2^3 = 8$ such $V$s.  So you are still missing a few...

Comment: My calculations give 1, 4, 17, 96, 801 for the start of the sequence, which does not appear in the OEIS (and neither does 2, 5, 18, 97, 802).

Comment: @antkam Thanks, I corrected my post!

Comment: [my Mathematica code](https://tio.run/##TVHNasMwDL7vKQSFnjxGD7usZGR0bJeOjXTsYsxwGy1JSezgKKEQ@uyZZO@wkyXr@7PcWaqxs9Sc7LL8jE67b/OQwZsvxxb1PNFlUIBlhXzUfiAFtm0VVN6XV3UDIADI4OAD5S@tJUKnP@2RuYV1FepGwdkomPncKHBXLs8KGin5emO2rBHlWeSPnyf@PMHtIwcZSE8MjV2BsROVScFz8L1OCZ25RimJyEqvwfa1/hc@Djk5z576Hl2pg/eC3FtRZKAxcJfDYTwOSINOtvFamPJceSW2eCLNoCoapIWsDKyFGxezR1dRnX9hILy8j7TzXe8dOtIrBeJpIMsgjXd@dJSvYB09CqQxOJ0EtDiKt9kuH6FhOv@NmKSt3huz/AI).

Comment: Stefan, do you mean $E = \{ (N, M) \in V\times V\mid |N\setminus M| = 1 \}$ or is it really $E = \{ (N, M) \in V\times V\mid M \subset N \cap |N\setminus M| = 1 \}$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I mean the latter condition (I updated my post), that is what I had in mind as seen in the picture. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rephrase.

Let $[a, b] = \{x \in \mathbb{N} : a \le x \le b\}$ and $[n] = [1, n]$.

Consider the directed graph $G_n = (V_n, E_n)$ with vertices $$V_n = \{[a, b] : 1 \le a \le b \le n\}$$ and edges $$E_n = \bigcup_{(a, b) \in V_n,\\ a < b} \{ ((a,b),(a+1,b)), ((a,b),(a,b-1)) \}$$

What you want to count are induced subgraphs $H \subseteq G_n$ which contain $[n]$ and for which every vertex is reachable from $[n]$.

---

I think it is useful to look at an isomorphic graph $G'_n \sim G_n$ whose vertices are pairs $$V'_n = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}: x+y < n\}$$ and edges $$E'_n = \bigcup_{x+y<n-1} \{ ((x,y),(x+1,y)), ((x,y),(x,y+1)) \}$$ where the vertex $(x,y) \in V'_n$ corresponds to the vertex $[x+1, n-y] \in V_n$. Then $G'_n \subset G'_{n+1}$ and the root vertex is always $(0, 0)$.

Observe that $G'_n$ is a layered graph: $(x,y)$ is in layer $x+y+1$, which contains $x+y+1$ vertices. The reachability of vertices in layer $k+1$ depends solely on which vertices from layer $k$ are in the subgraph, so we can count based on subsets of layers. Let $C_k: 2^{[0,k-1]} \to \mathbb{N}$ count the number of induced subgraphs of $G'_k$ which contain a given subset of $\{(0,k-1), (1,k-2), \ldots, (k-1,0)\}$. Then $$\begin{eqnarray}
C_1(\emptyset) &=& 0 \\
C_1(\{(0,0)\}) &=& 1 \\
C_{k+1}(S) &=& \sum_{T \in 2^{[0,k-1]} \\ S \subseteq N(T)} C_k(T) \\
N(T) &=& \bigcup_{x \in T} \{ x, x+1 \}
\end{eqnarray}$$

For [practical computation](https://tio.run/##bZHPboMwDMbP5CmsHqawMgk29VKVUx@h3CoU0TVAVDAoCeoqTXt15kBYV6mX/LG/z/456W@27vBjHM@yBDOc2sJcDHdruGWBKsEdIU0hpmtwU7I5Q8wC2RjpAk13FSdlIZ11L/DmdkqUnYZaVbXwNUHhY3nS/ni367TU/u95HoVv8D7GmKPe84lVd1fCOMYRJDmb@ivXVBdYSf4ewWWdTI1QflmxiHN4BZ7Abgcq9NTZ3dVI5KQMZ0CXPDzMkRELLeROvOav@vGQwzoFd8oIx9MtWaKVdtDo8n6Kz25A62asdNHXhuM006wyQ8v3FAlJS18iBBatFMJ9y0qItlAoxGo7D413/ISeYjNx9Vqh5Rg96RKO4y8) I think it's preferable to calculate $N(T)$ and then propagate to its subsets rather than to iterate over all $T$ checking whether $S$ is a subset.